# Beautifying binary tree in qtree

Tags: trees, qtree

I'm using qtree to draw beutiful trees. Except that my tree is not compact and beautiful as expected.

More specifically, I would expect the nodes at the same depth to be at the same level. Of course I read the documentation, and I tried to add a nice !{\qbalance} in my last node, but it did't helped a lot.

[image: Ugly latex tree]

```
\Tree[.$\norm{X}$ [.$\cdots$    [.$\norm{X^1}$   [.$\cdots$ 
[.$\norm{x^1(1)}$ ] [.$\norm{x^1(2)}$ ]  ] [ .$\cdots$ [.$\norm{x^1(3)}$ ] 
[.$\norm{x^1(T_k)}$ [.$\cdots$ [.$\norm{x_1^1(T_k)}$ ] [.$\norm{x^2(2)}$ ] ] 
[.$\cdots$ [.$\norm{x_{d-1}^1(T_k)}$ ] [.$\norm{x_d^1(T_k)}$ ]  ]  ]]] 
[.$\norm{X^2}$ ] ]     [.$\cdots$  [.$\norm{X^3}$ [.$\cdots$ ] [.$\cdots$ ]] 
[.$\norm{X^K}$   [.$\cdots$ ] [.$\cdots$ ] ] ] ]
```

Comment: please extend your code fragment to complete but small document. and reformat your code that it will be more readable.

Comment: not to have all code in one line. put (at least) each tree level in new line, for example. see similar questions and their answers in this site.

Comment: Sure Sure :D i thought it would have been done automatically bythe website... I dont think there are immediate useful ways of formatting a struture like that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qtree` package was designed for linguistic trees, and representing equal levels isn't really relevant for that. You would be better off using `forest` for your tree, since it does much better compaction and allows you to easily put nodes on equal levels.

Here's a version of your tree using `forest`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\lVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={math content}
[\norm{X} [\cdots    [\norm{X^1}   [\cdots 
[\norm{x^1(1)} ] [\norm{x^1(2)} ]  ] [ \cdots [\norm{x^1(3)} ] 
[\norm{x^1(T_k)} [\cdots [\norm{x_1^1(T_k)} ] [\norm{x^2(2)} ] ] 
[\cdots [\norm{x_{d-1}^1(T_k)} ] [\norm{x_d^1(T_k)} ]  ]  ]]] 
[\norm{X^2} ] ]     [\cdots  [\norm{X^3} [\cdots ] [\cdots ]] 
[\norm{X^K}   [\cdots ] [\cdots ] ] ] ] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]